# Qt Do my items are deleted after removing my scene ? Is my program well-architectured?

Tags: c++, qt, architecture

For some days now, I'm stuck. I'm not sure where my problem is, architecture ? Or just a protection to add for make my scene to not delete my items ?

This is how my program is architectured :

I have 1 GraphView + 1 GraphScene in all my ui, I switch ui with SetCentralWidget in my primary windows.

I saved all my Items in a QList or QVector in another class, all my windows have a pointer to this class passed by my primary windows. (yes, all my saved items are public: ... I know it's bad but how can I do ?).

So now I have this problem :

```
1 - My primary windows create and initiate my "storage class"
1 - my first ui add items in the QList (in storage class)
2 - I destroy this ui and pass to another ui
3 - I try to add items added before in my QList, and my program crash :

// PointMesure = QGraphicsRectItem and "d_e" is the pointer to the "stockage class"
foreach(PointMesure *point_mesure, d_e->liste_points_mesures) {
    scene->addItem(point_mesure);
}
```

So I think the problem is my items are deleted when I destroy the scene in my first ui ??

I'm a novice so maybe my program is not well architectured... What do you think ?

Be nice ;)

The Stockage class header :

```
class ConteneurDonneesEtude : public QObject
{
public:
    ConteneurDonneesEtude(QWidget *parent = 0);

public:

QList <PointMesure *> liste_points_mesures;     // Dérive de QGraphicsRectItem

private:
    QWidget *fenetre_principale;
};
```

I Load from a XML file :

```
void ConteneurDonneesEtude::creer_items_points_mesures(QXmlStreamReader *fichier_xml) {

    // Loading

    PointMesure *temp = new PointMesure();
    temp->setPos(QPointF(x, y));
    temp->setRect(QRect(-offset_centre, -offset_centre,
                        taille_point_mesure, taille_point_mesure));

    // set other things.... this part worked in another project anyway :)

    this->liste_points_mesures.insert(numero, temp);
}
```

My first ui GraphView :

Creation :

```
void FenetrePrincipale::slot_importer_etude() {
    fen_importer_etude = new FenetreImporterEtude(this, d_e);
    this->setCentralWidget(fen_importer_etude);

    connect(fen_importer_etude, SIGNAL(sig_continuer()), this, SLOT(slot_nommer_points()));
    connect(fen_importer_etude, SIGNAL(sig_retour()), this, SLOT(slot_importer_etude()));
}
```

And then :

```
void GraphImporterEtude::afficher_donnees_etude() {
    foreach(PointMesure *point_mesure, d_e->liste_points_mesures) {
        scene->addItem(point_mesure);
    }
}
```

I create another ui, setCentralWidgetwill auto. destroy the last ui :

```
void FenetrePrincipale::slot_nommer_points() {
    fen_nommer_points = new FenetreNommerPointsMesure(this, d_e);
    this->setCentralWidget(fen_nommer_points);

    connect(fen_nommer_points, SIGNAL(sig_continuer()), this, SLOT(slot_integration_tacheo()));
    connect(fen_nommer_points, SIGNAL(sig_retour()), this, SLOT(slot_importer_etude()));
}
```

And then

```
void GraphNommerPointsMesure::afficher_points_mesures_actifs() {
    foreach(PointMesure *point_mesure, d_e->liste_points_mesures) {
        if(point_mesure->actif) {
            scene->addItem(point_mesure);
        }
    }
}
```

Segmentation fault !

Comment: Post the relevant code, otherwise we can't say anything other than: "Yeah, you probably try to use something that's been deleted before". Also, instead of saying that "program crashes", which doesn't tell us much, please post full error message.

Comment: Ok, I'll post the code, but a lot of class are involved :)

Comment: The program stop responding, segmentation fault !

Comment: I hope these parts of my code will feet for you :)

Comment: If someone read this, I'm always here, waiting :)